# Return a changing key form JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I’m polling an API endpoint that has a changing key. It changes every day so its the key is the date in an ISO format ex (2020-02-04). I want to return all the data after that key so how can I use dot notation or something to pull in all the data after the date key. I have attached the sample JSON. Thank you.

```
{ "data": {
"2020-02-04": {
  "info_recv": 0,
  "dispatched": 0,
  "completed": 16,
  "completed_partial": 0,
  "failed": 0,
  "on_hold": 0,
  "return": 0,
  "all": 16,
  "unassigned": 0,
  "assigned": 16
}}}
```

Comment: Is the date key the only key in the data object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use moment.js:

```js
const moment = require('moment');
const input = { "data": {
    "2020-02-04": {
      "info_recv": 0,
      "dispatched": 0,
      "completed": 16,
      "completed_partial": 0,
      "failed": 0,
      "on_hold": 0,
      "return": 0,
      "all": 16,
      "unassigned": 0,
      "assigned": 16
}}}

const today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(today); // 2020-02-04

console.log(input.data[today]);
```

Comment: This will only work if the API is fetched on the same day the data is processed. Your approach removes the possibility to download the data daily and work on it every month, for instance. It also creates an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: I downvoted your solution for several reasons: 1) It makes assumptions that are not necessary to make, namely that the data is fetched on the same day that it is produced. 2) It requires a library that we can do without. 3) The ‘simple for loop’ might create problems on its own if not thought through right. Consider the case of a failed download. Then one date is missing in the data, which requires special attention in the loop. Since we’re helping a new programmer, I think fewer stumbling blocks are better.

Comment: @Viet thanks for the help and suggestions I got it all working. Appreciate your time

Comment: @Luke you're welcome, please mark the correct answer to close the thread.

Answer (score -1):

Let’s start by parsing the JSON to a plain object. This will make dealing with it easier. We also access the `data` portion of the JSON, since that’s what you’re dealing with.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(theJSON).data
```

The function [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of all keys that are on an object. In your instance, `Object.keys(data)` will return the array `["2020-02-04"]`. We’ll store the key.

```js
const dateKey = Object.keys(data)[0]; // "2020-02-04"
```

Now you can just access the data you’re interested via simple array access using the variable:

```js
const coolData = data[dateKey];
```

Should there be other keys in the data besides the date key, you can filter the array `Object.keys` returns using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). To parse a date you’d use

```js
const regEx = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/
```

This will match four digits (year) followed by a dash and two digits (month) followed by a dash and two digits (day).

```js
const dateKey = Object.keys(data)
    .filter(key => regEx.test(key))[0]
```

This iterates over every key returned by `Object.keys` and throw it out of the array if the regular expression does not match it. What’s left is an array with just the date key, which you can get as before.

Comment: thanks for the help I got it all working. Appreciate your time